# Eclipse/Java: can you import custom characters?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I want to start on my first real Java project--a top-to-bottom GUI. However, part of it requires me to have a 1:1 translation from english characters to custom created ones (A --> square, B--> 3 perpendicular lines, etc.).

Is there a way to import custom characters? What about into a GUI text-box?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean a custom font (with non-Unicode glyphs)? Or "just" a mapping from alphabet to other Unicode characters?

Comment: The latter seems to be the easiest, so I'll start with that for now.

Comment: Creating custom font is not that hard using fontforge